# Navigation Bar and navigation items not visible on runtime

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why SignIn and SignUp navigation Bar and the back buttons are not visible even when embedding both of these views in the navigation controllers.
Is there anything else we have to do in code. All top bars are inferred in this case and I haven't touched the visibility of any.

Comment: Delete the first navigation controller. You cannot put a navigation controller inside a navigation controller. Also you cannot put a tab bar controller inside a navigation controller. Everything about your architecture is illegal!

Comment: I deleted the first navigation controller, it works but thing is I'm using swreveal viewcontroller through which I use this code                         let  mainStoryBoard :UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let desController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInCreate") as? SignInCreate
        let newFrontViewController  = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController!)
        revealViewController()?.pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true) and SignInCreate is tab bar controller in this case

Comment: I don't care about "the thing is". That wasn't part of your question. I can only deal with the actual question you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no back button because there is nowhere to go back to. Your sign up and sign in view controllers are the *root* view controllers of their respective navigation controllers.

There is no visible title because what you are looking at is the navigation item of the tab bar controller, which has no title.

Your architecture posits a navigation controller insider a navigation controller, which is illegal:

```
nav controller -> tab bar controller -> nav controller
```

You can't do that.

Also you can't put a tab bar controller inside a navigation controller. A navigation interface inside a tabbed interface is fine (as illustrate in Apple's own docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller). The reverse, a tabbed interface inside a navigation interface, is not.

The simplest solution is to eliminate the first navigation controller completely, as there is no need for it (you are not pushing anything onto it beyond its root view controller).

Answer (score 0):

IN SIMPLE TERMS

Logically, your `Tabbar` should not be embedded in a `UINavigation Controller`. Instead, delete the NavigationController and make the `Tabbar` the root `Viewcontroller` then embed each `UIViewcontroller` in a separate `Navigation controller`

Comment: No different from what I said. :)

Comment: @matt sorry I didn’t read your answer. I just answered the question directly from my mobile.